# 2 API Calls with Axios, both show up in local server - but only one appears deployed

Tags: reactjs, api, axios

I made 2 API calls in React with Axios. In my local server both calls appear, after being deployed to Netify, only the first API call appears. I don't know what is causing it bc I have no error messages. 
Right image is after it's been deployed, and the left image is the one on the local server. I XXXed my key, so it doesn't appear in the code

[image]

```
import axios from 'axios';

const API_URL = 'https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?sources=techcrunch&apiKey=XXXX';
const API_URL2= 'http://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?sources=ars-technica&apiKey=XXXX';

export const getNews = async () => {
  const result = await axios.get(API_URL)
  .then(response => {
  return response.data.articles;
  });
  return(result);
}

export const getNews2 = async () => {
  const result = await axios.get(API_URL2)
  .then(response => {
  console.log(response.data)
  return response.data.articles;
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    // handle error
    console.log(error);
  })
  .finally(function () {
    // always executed
  });
  return(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

Why first is https and second http ?

Comment: Thank you!! That was the issue!